# Group Access to pages in laravel

Tags: laravel, access-control

Inside an AuthServiceProvider Access Control is defined. I need to check permission to access page in the routes web.php.
If user is not admin then page should redirect error page or page not found .

How to create a middleware that redirect to 404 page if somebody tries to access the page from the url.

**AuthServiceProvider**

```
Gate::define('isAdmin',function($user){
    return $user->type === 'admin';
});

Gate::define('isGeneralUser',function($user){
    return $user->type === 'user';
});

Gate::define('isPaidUser',function($user){
    return $user->type === 'paid';
});
```

**Route** web.php

```
if (Gate::allows('isAdmin') && Gate::allows('isPaidUser')) {
    Route::get('/home-page', function () {
        return view('pages.trades');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**create middleware**

```
class CheckIsTradeable
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->user()->type !== 'admin' && $request->user()->type !== 'paid') {
            abort(404);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

**Register inside `Kernal`**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'isTradeable' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckIsTradeable::class,
];
```

**and check it in your route**

```
Route::get('/home-page', function () {
    return view('pages.trades');
})->middleware('isTradeable');
```

Comment: What if I have more roles

Comment: @BLPraveen i don't understand

Comment: @BLPraveen there are two way you can do that, you can create another middleware for check paid user or check both situation in one middleware, name your middleware something like **isTradeable**.

Comment: How to check both situation in one middleware